# Is there a way to Make expandable listview expand upward in android?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

The regular expandable listview in android is expanding only downward.
Is there any way to Make it expand upward?

I thought maybe I needed to switch between the place of the parent and the place of the child, but I cant find any way to switch between them.

Is it possible? if so, how?
If not, any other way you can suggest?

Comment: I'm pretty much sure that it is possible, yet you'd have to customize the existing class, extend `ExpandableListView` and overwrite methods, which are responsible for the expanding behavior. Also, I'm pretty sure this customization won't be easy to achieve. Before even trying such an intervention, I'd search for alternatives - there are tons of libraries that do similar things.